# Proof around Rolle's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f(x)=\exp(\sin(2\pi x))$. I'm trying to prove that there is $a\in[0,1]$ such that, for $(n_r)$ a sequence of integers tending to $\infty$ (by this I mean $n_r$ tends to $\infty$ as $r$ tends to $\infty$), $f^{(n_r)}$ has a root in $(a-0.0005,a+0.0005)$.

I've noticed $f(x+1)=f(x)$ so that Rolle's Theorem gives that there is $\alpha\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(\alpha)=0$. And more generally for any $n=1,2,...$ , we have that $f^{(n)}$ has a root in $(0,1)$.

From there, I have absolutely no idea in which direction going... Can you hint me please? Help me?

I'm really nowhere, thank you!

Comment: What's the quantifier on $n_r$? and what is $r$, for that matter?

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to answer your question but $(n_r)$ is a sequence of integers such that $n_r$ tends to $\infty$ as $r$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: @tomasz I've edited the post

Comment: Do you mean that *for all* such sequences or that there *exists* such a sequence?

Comment: @tomasz I'm trying to get one a such that one sequence is such that the conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

For each $n$, let $x_n\in[0,1]$ be a root of $f^{(n)}$.  (You've explained how to show that roots exist.)  Now $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $[0,1]$; by Bolzano-Weierstrass, ...